# Lazy initialized field with changed ctor param?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, lazy-initialization

This is the syntax for a Field which is lazy initialized.

```
public class MyClass
{
    string _cat;
    public MyClass(string Category)
    {
        _cat=Category;
    }

    MyExpensive _expensive;
    public MyExpensive Expensive
    {
        get 
        {
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _expensive, () = > new MyExpensive ());
            return _expensive;
        }
    }
}
```

But what if I need to create `new MyExpensive`  with a *run-time  ctor params* ? (according to a flow logic)

I don't want to create a flag field and then in do a lot's of `IF's`

I mean ,sometimes I need to run `new MyExpensive ("picture")` and sometimes `new MyExpensive ("flowers")`

How can I do that ?

*(exclude creating a lazy field for each category - )*

Comment: How are you getting the string value? If that's also from the caller, what would you expect if you get a different value on the second call?

Comment: @JonSkeet  There will be only one string value param (in my case)

Comment: That doesn't actually answer either of my questions though...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited the code. However I can see now that it was a stupid question. because I could just do `new MyExpensive (_cat)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing anything *expensive*, you should do it in a method, not a property.

Properties should be *fast* and *inexpensive* as this is the normal expectation by most programmers (principle of least astonishment).

In your case, don't have a getter - use:

```
public MyExpensive GetExpensive()
{
    LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _expensive, () = > new MyExpensive ());
    return _expensive;
}
```

And of course, you have have parameterized overloads.

Comment: Oded where is the ctor param here ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You can have an overload that takes a string parameter and pass it to the `ctor`.

Comment: please notice the edited code above. it was a really stupid question cause I could have done like this and just execute the ctor with `new MyExpensive (_cat)`